# How to properly return or display multiple rows to html from the result of mysql query in render template

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, mysql-workbench

I'm new to this python and flask.

My problem is how to return values from mysql query to show to html. I currently solve that problem, But the return in my query includes {{ databasecolumnname :data here }}

Like this

```
0 {'username': 'unu'}   0 {'email': '1@1.com'}

1 {'username': 'dos'}   1 {'email': 'two@two.com'}

2 {'username': 'test1'} 2 {'email': 'testtest@test.com'}
```

All I want to do is to remove the { } and the column name of the database. Is there a way to do this with my current code?

I want the return to be like this

```
0 unu 1@1.com

1 dos two@two.com

2 test1 testtest@test.com
```

---

Im just learning on how to code.

I have tried to fetchone and loop it,also used sql alchemy. All I want to do is the return it cleanly without the open brace and column name.

I have this code on my main.py

@app.route('/flaskapp/profile2')

```
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM accounts")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute('SELECT email FROM accounts')
    data2 = cursor.fetchall()


    return render_template('profile2.html', data=data , data2=data2)

-----------------------------------------




Then I have this HTML template for the view(profile2)



{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Profile2{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Profile Views</h2>
<div>
    <p>Details are below:</p>
    <table>

        <tr>

            <td>username</td>
            <td>email </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>0 {{ data[0] }}</th>
            <td>0 {{ data2[0] }} </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1 {{ data[1] }}</th>
            <td>1 {{ data2[1] }} </td>

        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>2 {{ data[2] }}</th>
            <td>2 {{ data2[2] }} </td>

        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>3 {{ data[3] }}</th>
            <td>3 {{ data2[3] }} </td>

        </tr>

    </table>
    p
</div>
{% endblock %}


-------------------------

This app returns this


0 {'username': 'unu'}   0 {'email': '1@1.com'}

1 {'username': 'dos'}   1 {'email': 'two@two.com'}

2 {'username': 'test1'} 2 {'email': 'testtest@test.com'}


------------------





I want the HTML output to be this.


0 unu 1@1.com

1 dos two@two.com

2 test1 testtest@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

even I had the same query. Try **@foreach**

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
<div class="col-md-2" >
 <h4 class=""> {{ $item -> name }}</h4>
  <div class="action-wrap">
    <div class="price-wrap h5 text-center">
      <span class="price-new"><b> ${{ $item->price }} </b></span>
    </div>
   </div>           
</div>
@endforeach
```

I used the same and resulted just like how you wanted.